# OSX Yosemite Openmdao error during easy_install sphinx - NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite, openmdao

What does `NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined` mean? What could be the cause of this error?

**EDIT**

It seems like this is an issue with openMDAO. This error is raised when I run easy_install in the openMDAO 0.10.3 environment.

For whatever reason, I cannot recreate the `easy_install sphinx` error I originally posted. However, I get a similar failure from `easy_install zope.interface`. Here is the output (`test` still returns no errors):

```
(openmdao-0.10.3.2)Julians-MacBook-Pro:openmdao-0.10.3.2 julian$ easy_install zope.interface
Searching for zope.interface
Best match: zope.interface 4.1.2
Removing zope.interface 3.6.1 from easy-install.pth file
zope.interface 4.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for zope.interface
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.9.5', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1992, in main

  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1979, in with_ei_usage

  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1996, in <lambda>

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 380, in run

  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 620, in easy_install

  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 706, in process_distribution

  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 631, in resolve
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2489, in requires
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2700, in _dep_map
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2733, in _compute_dependencies
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2730, in reqs_for_extra
  File "/Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/_markerlib/markers.py", line 109, in marker_fn
  File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys_platform' is not defined
```

Output from `envdump`:

```
(openmdao-0.10.3.2)Julians-MacBook-Pro:openmdao-0.10.3.2 julian$ envdump
Date of environment dump: 
2015-06-03 18:55:59.761840


================PYTHON INFORMATION================
Python Version:  2.7.9
Python Compiler:  GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)
Python Build:  ('default', 'Apr  7 2015 07:58:25')
Python Path:  
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.4-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.6-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SetupDocs-1.0.5-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson-0.3.3-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobyla-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conmin-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator-3.2.0-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.10-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.8.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newsumt-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.bar3simulation-0.10.3.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.enginedesign-0.10.3.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.expected_improvement-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.mdao-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.nozzle_geometry_doe-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.simple-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.test-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.units-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.util-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ordereddict-1.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycrypto-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-1.5.7-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2011k-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slsqp-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits-4.3.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh-0.15.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.gui-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pathtools-0.1.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyV3D-0.4.4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzmq-13.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watchdog-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/EasyProcess-0.1.4-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyVirtualDisplay-0.1.0-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/entrypoint2-0.0.5-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.testing-0.1.2a-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mocker-1.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/path.py-2.2.2-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.exceptions-3.6.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.testing-4.1.1-py2.7.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.testrunner-4.0.4-py2.7.egg
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/akima-1.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pBEAM-0.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python27.zip
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh-0.26.1-py2.7.egg
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.11-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/lib-old
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages



================PLATFORM INFORMATION================
Platform:  Darwin
Operating System:  Darwin-14.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
Architecture:  ('64bit', '')


================ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES================
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render:  /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.JH4nN1Inmx/Render
DISPLAY:  /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.tm06HV2aww/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
HOME:  /Users/julian
LANG:  en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME:  julian
OLDPWD:  /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes
PATH:  
    /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/sbin
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin
    /opt/local/bin
    /opt/local/sbin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/sbin
    /opt/local/bin
    /opt/local/sbin
    /opt/local/bin
    /opt/local/sbin
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
    /opt/local/bin
    /opt/local/sbin
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
    /opt/X11/bin
    /usr/local/git/bin

PS1:  (openmdao-0.10.3.2)\h:\W \u\$ 
PWD:  /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2
SHELL:  /bin/bash
SHLVL:  1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK:  /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.PEtUXA9ewg/Listeners
TERM:  xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM:  Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION:  343.7
TERM_SESSION_ID:  8CFDBF2D-2121-4A8F-88FD-C503C5DFE1A6
TMPDIR:  /var/folders/0h/t_511_2d4cq81289ym9pn6g40000gn/T/
USER:  julian
VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT:  yes
VIRTUAL_ENV:  /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2
XPC_FLAGS:  0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME:  0
_:  /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin/envdump
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING:  0x1F5:0x0:0x0

================ALIASES================


================COMPILER INFORMATION================
Compilers:  
  gcc FOUND:  /usr/local/bin/gcc
  gcc version info: 
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

  gcc FOUND:  /usr/local/bin/gcc
  gcc version info: 
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

  gcc FOUND:  /usr/local/lib/gcc

ERROR searching for compiler:
[Errno 13] Permission denied


================PYTHON PACKAGES================

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    setuptools-0.9.5-py2.7.egg

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Jinja2-2.4-py2.7.egg:
    jinja2

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.6-py2.7.egg:
    pyevolve

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.3.1-py2.7.egg:
    pygments

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SetupDocs-1.0.5-py2.7.egg:
    setupdocs

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argparse-1.2.1-py2.7.egg:
    argparse

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bson-0.3.3-py2.7.egg:
    bson

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cobyla-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    cobyla

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conmin-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    conmin

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/decorator-3.2.0-py2.7.egg:
    decorator

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.10-py2.7.egg:
    docutils

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.8.1-py2.7.egg:
    networkx

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newsumt-1.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    newsumt

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg:
    nose

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.bar3simulation-0.10.3.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg:
    openmdao.examples.bar3simulation

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.enginedesign-0.10.3.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg:
    openmdao.examples.enginedesign

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.expected_improvement-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.examples.expected_improvement

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.mdao-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.examples.mdao

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.nozzle_geometry_doe-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.examples.nozzle_geometry_doe

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.examples.simple-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.examples.simple

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.lib-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.lib

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.main-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.main

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.test-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.test

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.units-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.units

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.util-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.util

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ordereddict-1.1-py2.7.egg:
    ordereddict

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycrypto-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    Crypto

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-1.5.7-py2.7.egg:
    pyparsing

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2011k-py2.7.egg:
    pytz

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg:
    requests

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/slsqp-1.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    slsqp

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traits-4.3.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    traits

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    yaml
    _yaml

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/argh-0.15.1-py2.7.egg:
    argh

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao.gui-0.10.3.2-py2.7.egg:
    openmdao.gui

from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    pathtools-0.1.2-py2.7.egg

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyV3D-0.4.4-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    pyV3D

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyzmq-13.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    zmq

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.2.1-py2.7.egg:
    tornado

from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/watchdog-0.6.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg:
    _watchdog_fsevents
    watchdog

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/EasyProcess-0.1.4-py2.7.egg:
    easyprocess

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyVirtualDisplay-0.1.0-py2.7.egg:
    pyvirtualdisplay

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/entrypoint2-0.0.5-py2.7.egg:
    entrypoint2

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lazr.testing-0.1.2a-py2.7.egg:
    lazr.testing

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mocker-1.1-py2.7.egg:
    mocker

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/path.py-2.2.2-py2.7.egg:
    path
    test_path

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py2.7.egg:
    selenium

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.exceptions-3.6.1-py2.7.egg:
    zope.exceptions

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.testing-4.1.1-py2.7.egg:
    zope.testing

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.testrunner-4.0.4-py2.7.egg:
    zope.testrunner

from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    akima-1.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg

from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    pBEAM-0.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg

from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    _markerlib
    AccessControl
    Acquisition
    alabaster
    algopy
    App
    babel
    blockspring
    BTrees
    colorama
    ComputedAttribute
    custom_fixers
    DateTime
    dateutil
    DocumentTemplate
    docutils
    ExtensionClass
    Globals
    HelpSys
    initgroups
    IPython
    jinja2
    latexcodec
    Lifetime
    lxml
    mahotas
    markupsafe
    matplotlib
    mechanize
    MethodObject
    Missing
    MultiMapping
    nose
    numpy
    numpydoc
    OFS
    oset
    pandas
    pbr
    Persistence
    persistent
    PIL
    pip
    pkg_resources
    pockets
    pybtex
    pygments
    pyopt
    pytz
    Record
    requests
    RestrictedPython
    reStructuredText
    scipy
    setuptools
    Signals
    skimage
    snowballstemmer
    sphinx
    sphinx_rtd_theme
    spoofmac
    stevedore
    tempstorage
    Testing
    tests
    transaction
    TreeDisplay
    virtualenv_support
    webdav
    xlrd
    ZConfig
    zdaemon
    ZEO
    zExceptions
    zLOG
    zmq
    ZODB
    Zope2
    ZopeUndo
    ZPublisher
    ZServer
    ZTUtils

from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    argh-0.26.1-py2.7.egg

from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
    PyYAML-3.11-py2.7-macosx-10.10-x86_64.egg

from /Users/julian/Desktop/girrafes/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7:
    distutils
    encodings

from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7:
    bsddb
    compiler
    ctypes
    curses
    distutils
    email
    encodings
    ensurepip
    hotshot
    idlelib
    importlib
    json
    lib2to3
    logging
    multiprocessing
    pydoc_data
    sqlite3
    test
    unittest
    wsgiref
    xml

from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac:
    Carbon

from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages:
    _builtinSuites
    CodeWarrior
    Explorer
    Finder
    Netscape
    StdSuites
    SystemEvents
    Terminal
(openmdao-0.10.3.2)Julians-MacBook-Pro:openmdao-0.10.3.2 julian$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT @kilojoules: I have seen your edit and new posting, and I will take a look at it when I get home to my Yosemite machine.
/EDIT

Note: I wanted to make this a comment, since it does not solve your problem, but I lack the reputation to comment.

Here is another data point for you:  I have OS X 10.10.3, Python 2.7.9, and I just downloaded OpenMDAO 0.10.3.2 in an attempt to replicate your problem:

```
kmarstel$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.3
BuildVersion:   14D136

kmarstel$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

After installing OpenMDAO 0.10.3.2:

```
The OpenMDAO virtual environment has been installed in
 /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2

From /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2, type:

. bin/activate

to activate your environment and start using OpenMDAO.

kmarstel$  . bin/activate
(openmdao-0.10.3.2) kmarstel$
```

So installation and activation produced no errors.  Next, I tried to `easy_install sphinx`, like you did, but it found that the OpenMDAO install had already installed 1.2.2 into my virtualenv (as it should have):

```
(openmdao-0.10.3.2) kmarstel$ easy_install sphinx
Searching for sphinx
Best match: Sphinx 1.2.2
Processing Sphinx-1.2.2-py2.7.egg
Sphinx 1.2.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing sphinx-apidoc script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing sphinx-build script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing sphinx-quickstart script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing sphinx-autogen script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
```

So I thought I'd try explicitly installing 1.3.1, the version you're having trouble with, but it worked just fine:

```
(openmdao-0.10.3.2) kmarstel$ easy_install sphinx==1.3.1
Searching for sphinx==1.3.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx/
Best match: Sphinx 1.3.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Sphinx/Sphinx-1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=8786a194acf9673464c5455b11fd4332
Processing Sphinx-1.3.1.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-WCmHmr/Sphinx-1.3.1/setup.cfg
Running Sphinx-1.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-WCmHmr/Sphinx-1.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-YQEdHB
warning: no files found matching 'TODO'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Removing Sphinx 1.2.2 from easy-install.pth file
Adding Sphinx 1.3.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing sphinx-apidoc script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing sphinx-build script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing sphinx-quickstart script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing sphinx-autogen script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for sphinx==1.3.1
Searching for sphinx-rtd-theme>=0.1,<0.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sphinx_rtd_theme/
Best match: sphinx-rtd-theme 0.1.8
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/sphinx_rtd_theme/sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8.tar.gz#md5=713ce7c53239449bdd799385577329ee
Processing sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-yPgeif/sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8/setup.cfg
Running sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-yPgeif/sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8/egg-dist-tmp-uQyFTV
Adding sphinx-rtd-theme 0.1.8 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme-0.1.8-py2.7.egg
Searching for alabaster>=0.7,<0.8
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/alabaster/
Best match: alabaster 0.7.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/alabaster/alabaster-0.7.4.tar.gz#md5=ba31bf652194200428aa4e3d976f5ccd
Processing alabaster-0.7.4.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-k4wKBC/alabaster-0.7.4/setup.cfg
Running alabaster-0.7.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-k4wKBC/alabaster-0.7.4/egg-dist-tmp-ni9W8x
warning: no files found matching 'README.md'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.*.swp' found under directory 'alabaster'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
alabaster.__init__: module references __file__
Adding alabaster 0.7.4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alabaster-0.7.4-py2.7.egg
Searching for babel>=1.3
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/babel/
Best match: Babel 1.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/B/Babel/Babel-1.3.tar.gz#md5=5264ceb02717843cbc9ffce8e6e06bdb
Processing Babel-1.3.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-_xXBvb/Babel-1.3/setup.cfg
Running Babel-1.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-_xXBvb/Babel-1.3/egg-dist-tmp-HhDGYg
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
Adding Babel 1.3 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pybabel script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Babel-1.3-py2.7.egg
Searching for snowballstemmer>=1.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/snowballstemmer/
Best match: snowballstemmer 1.2.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/snowballstemmer/snowballstemmer-1.2.0.tar.gz#md5=51f2ef829db8129dd0f2354f0b209970
Processing snowballstemmer-1.2.0.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-ICmHM_/snowballstemmer-1.2.0/setup.cfg
Running snowballstemmer-1.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-ICmHM_/snowballstemmer-1.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-zCKeIp
warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'src'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding snowballstemmer 1.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowballstemmer-1.2.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for docutils>=0.11
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/docutils/
Best match: docutils 0.12
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/docutils/docutils-0.12.tar.gz#md5=4622263b62c5c771c03502afa3157768
Processing docutils-0.12.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-sztGuq/docutils-0.12/setup.cfg
Running docutils-0.12/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-sztGuq/docutils-0.12/egg-dist-tmp-grmcuq
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'extras'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.cvsignore' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found under directory '*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found under directory '*'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
docutils.parsers.rst.directives.misc: module references __file__
docutils.writers.docutils_xml: module references __path__
docutils.writers.html4css1.__init__: module references __file__
docutils.writers.latex2e.__init__: module references __file__
docutils.writers.odf_odt.__init__: module references __file__
docutils.writers.pep_html.__init__: module references __file__
docutils.writers.s5_html.__init__: module references __file__
Removing docutils 0.10 from easy-install.pth file
Adding docutils 0.12 to easy-install.pth file
Installing rst2html.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2latex.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2man.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2odt.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2odt_prepstyles.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2pseudoxml.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2s5.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2xetex.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rst2xml.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin
Installing rstpep2html.py script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils-0.12-py2.7.egg
Searching for Pygments>=2.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/Pygments/
Best match: Pygments 2.0.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pygments/Pygments-2.0.2.tar.gz#md5=238587a1370d62405edabd0794b3ec4a
Processing Pygments-2.0.2.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-yfhxzw/Pygments-2.0.2/setup.cfg
Running Pygments-2.0.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/s6/zxc02fzj7c10mkt6vgw71k0w0000gn/T/easy_install-yfhxzw/Pygments-2.0.2/egg-dist-tmp-XfZmGn
Removing Pygments 1.3.1 from easy-install.pth file
Adding Pygments 2.0.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pygmentize script to /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin

Installed /Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Pygments-2.0.2-py2.7.egg
Finished processing dependencies for sphinx==1.3.1
(openmdao-0.10.3.2) kmarstel$
```

Finally, I looked to make sure that Python is my virtualenv Python, and that the easy_install truly worked:

```
(openmdao-0.10.3.2) kmarstel$ which python
/Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/bin/python
(openmdao-0.10.3.2) kmarstel$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan  7 2015, 11:49:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sphinx
>>> sphinx.__version__
'1.3.1'
>>> sphinx.__file__
'/Users/kmarstel/openmdao-0.10.3.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/sphinx/__init__.pyc'
>>> from sphinx import setup_command
>>>
```

So, I was unable to replicate your problem, so it does not appear to inherently be a problem with OpenMDAO.  Next steps might be to take a look at an OpenMDAO command called `envdump` You invoke that command from an activated OpenMDAO prompt, and it dumps out all of your environment configuration.  If you want to post the output of that (it will be lengthy) I can compare it to my own to see if there are any strange differences.

Good luck.

--Keith

Comment: Hi Keith. Thank you for your detailed reply. I sat down to recreate this familiar error and, to my surprise, `easy_install sphinx` did not fail. However, `easy_install zope.interface` fails in a similar manner. I am posting the results of this comand as well as `envdump` now.

Comment: I updated my question to include the easy_install zope.interface failure as well as the output from envdump. Due to space constraints I had to delete some of my original post. However, I believe all of the important information is still here

Comment: I marked this as correct because this answer correctly diagnosed that I had a configuration issue

Answer (score 3):

I think your setup tools package might be out of date. Could you try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

then re-run your installer

Comment: pip says my setuptools are up-to-date